# PyQt5: Taking screenshot gives error (xcb)

Tags: python, pyqt

I am new to python, so this may be easy, and I apologize if it is, but I can't find a way to do this. The problem is that when I call snip(), no matter where, it will take a screenshot once, but when I press the button again it stops, freezes and then force quits. So far I've encountered 2 different errors. One is the following, whenever I click the button a second time:

*Gdk-Message: python3: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Killed*

Another one I find in the bigger project is the following one:

*[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue*

*[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called*

*[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.*

*python3: ../../src/xcb_io.c:259: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.*

*Aborted*

Is there a way to take a screenshot everytime I click the button without this problem? Here's a simplified code of the problem. Thank you for any help you guys can provide.

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow,self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def button_clicked(self):
        self.label.setText("you pressed the button")
        self.snip()     #heres the problem
        self.update()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Tech With Tim")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("my first label!")
        self.label.move(50,50)

        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText("click me!")
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def update(self):
        self.label.adjustSize()

    def snip(self):
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(200, 300, 400, 500))
        img.show()

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

Comment: on Linux you can use program `scrot`  to create screenshot in console. If you use it with python module `subprocess` then you may get image in file and you will have to display image in your program.

Comment: This does work, I didn't know about `subprocess`. Thank you